# Python threading with queue: how to avoid to use join?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, queue, can-bus

I have a scenario with 2 threads:

1. a thread waiting for messages from a socket (embedded in a C library - blocking call is "Barra.ricevi") then putting an element on a queue
2. a thread waiting to get element from the queue and do something

Sample code

```
import Barra
import Queue    
import threading

posQu = Queue.Queue(maxsize=0)

def threadCAN():
    while True:
        canMsg = Barra.ricevi("can0")
        if canMsg[0] == 'ERR':
            print (canMsg)
        else:
            print ("Enqueued message"), canMsg
            posQu.put(canMsg)

thCan = threading.Thread(target = threadCAN)
thCan.daemon = True
thCan.start()

while True:
    posMsg = posQu.get()
    print ("Messagge from the queue"), posMsg
```

The result is that every time a new message is coming from the socket a new element is added to the queue, BUT the main thread that should get items from the queue is never woke up.

The output is as follow:

> Enqueued message
>
> Enqueued message
>
> Enqueued message
>
> Enqueued message

I expected to have:

> Enqueued message
>
> Messagge from the queue
>
> Enqueued message
>
> Messagge from the queue

The only way to solve this issue seams to add the line:

```
posQu.join()
```

at the end of the thread waiting for messages from the socket, and the line:

```
posQu.task_done()
```

at the end of the main thread.

In this case, after that a new message has been received from the socket, the thread is blocking waiting for the main thread to process the enqueued item.

Unfortunately this isn't the desired behavior since I would like a thread always ready to get messages from a socket and not waiting for a job to be compleated from another thread.

What I am doing wrong ?
Thanks

Andrew
(Italy)

Comment: Can you give us a self-contained example, that doesn't require that `Barra` library? Because when I replace that with code that just gives it a random value, it works just as you'd like it do. So I suspect that there's a problem in some other code, not in this code.

Comment: Since Pastebin seems to be down right now, here's my changed: replace `import Barra` with `import random`, and `canMsg = barra.cicevi("can0")` with `canMsg = ['ERR'] if random.random() < .25 else [0, 1, 2]`, then run your code, and you'll see the enqueues and messages interleaved (often on the same line).

Comment: Also, does CAN-bus actually have anything to do with this program? (Maybe you're using an embedded-linux system that doesn't have pthreads, so it's using dummy threads? That probably _could_ cause this problem…)

Comment: With your changes given in your comment I cannot reproduce the problem.  I get messages about the enqueuing and the dequeuing.  It could, however, be related to a strange and in your case malfunctioning scheduling.  Maybe the writer thread never gives up the processor, and the system because of this (and a bad scheduling mechanism) never activates the reader thread.  Have you tried using `Queue(1)` instead of `Queue(0)`?  This could put the writer thread to sleep as soon as it tries to put a second message into the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because your `Barra` does not release the global interpreter lock (GIL) when `Barra.ricevi`. You may want to check this though.

The GIL ensures that only one thread can run at any one time (limiting the usefulness of threads in a multi-processor system). The GIL switches threads every 100 "ticks" -- a tick loosely mapping to bytecode instructions. See [here](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf) for more details.

In your producer thread, not much happens outside of the C-library call. This means the producer thread will get to call `Barra.ricevi` a great many times before the GIL switches to another thread.

Solutions to this are to, in terms of increasing complexity:

- Call `time.sleep(0)` after adding an item to the queue. This yields the thread so that another thread can run.
- Use `sys.setcheckinterval()` to lower the amount of "ticks" executed before switching threads. This is will come at the cost of making the program much more computationally expensive.
- Use `multiprocessing` rather than `threading`. This includes using `multiprocessing.Queue` instead of `Queue.Queue`.
- Modify `Barra` so that it does release the GIL when its functions are called.

Example using `multiprocessing`. Be aware that when using multiprocessing, your processes no longer have an implied shared state. You will need to have a look at multiprocessing to see how to pass information between processes.

```
import Barra  
import multiprocessing

def threadCAN(posQu):
    while True:
        canMsg = Barra.ricevi("can0")
        if canMsg[0] == 'ERR':
            print(canMsg)
        else:
            print("Enqueued message", canMsg)
            posQu.put(canMsg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    posQu = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=0)
    procCan = multiprocessing.Process(target=threadCAN, args=(posQu,))
    procCan.daemon = True
    procCan.start()

    while True:
        posMsg = posQu.get()
        print("Messagge from the queue", posMsg)
```

Comment: Excellent!! Thanks a lot. It was GIL !
I have changed my Barra library adding macros: Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS and Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS, before and after the I/O blocking call.