# Is possible to process queue without calling join method?

Tags: python-3.x

I've 3 workers waiting to stuffs come to queue but these workers just start their work when i call `join()` method.

I'm working with this example;
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#examples

Is possible to enqueue something and process right away without calling `join`? if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sometimes process a queue without calling the join, but it is really advised that you wait.
`.join()` ensures that each item in your queue has been "gotten" and processed, and if you continue before join is finished, you may end up with an incomplete or fragemented queue structure.

To answer your question, **theoretically yes, but it is highly recommended to use `.join()`**

An example of not using `.join()`, but still mimicking its capability, can be [found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418789/python-threading-with-queue-how-to-avoid-to-use-join)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

Comment: can you show me how? i've tried remove the `join` but the process was not processed.

Comment: Are you using the example from the code that you posted?

Comment: yes Jerry, i made my adaptations but the concept is the same

Comment: I don't think you can in that example. It is important to understand what `.join()` does, which allows your queue to finish building. Imagine it like having a restaurant full of people; you are closing the restaurant before you allow the line (queue) to finish building. Theoretically, you can do that, but in practice it is very difficult.

Comment: can you post a simple example?

Comment: @RafaAcioly I added that. Please mark the answer as "Accepted" if this answers your original question. The example I posted shows somebody reworking code to avoid using `.join()`